# Writing Dirichlet series in infinite product.

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, special-functions, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

In Serre's $A \, Course\, In \,Arithmetic$, it says the following:

> $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}c(n)/n^s= \prod\limits_{p \,\rm prime}\frac{1}{1-c(p)p^{-s}+p^{2k-1-2s}}$
>
> $\Longleftrightarrow$
>
> $\left\{\begin{array}{ll}   
> c(m)c(n)=c(mn) && (m,n)=1 \\
> c(p)c(p^n)=c(p^{n+1})+p^{2k-1}c(p^{n-1})&& p \,{\rm prime} \,{\rm and} \, n\geq 1, 
> \end{array}\right.$

${}$

It proves the $\Longleftarrow$ part in the book by $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}c(n)/n^s=\prod\limits_{p \, {\rm prime}}(\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty{c(p^n)p^{-ns}})$, and expands  $(\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty{c(p^n)p^{-ns}})(1-c(p)p^{-s}+p^{2k-1-2s})$ to get a power series in $p^{-s}$, and by relations of $c(mn), c(p^n)$ above, get it is equal to $c(1)=1$, hence $\prod\limits_{p \,\rm prime}(\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty{c(p^n)p^{-ns}})({1-c(p)p^{-s}+p^{2k-1-2s}})=\prod\limits_{p \,\rm prime}1=1$, and the $\Longleftarrow$ part is done.

${}$

But the book doesn't prove the $\Longrightarrow$ part. In order for 
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}c(n)/n^s=\prod\limits_{p \, {\rm prime}}(\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty{c(p^n)p^{-ns}})$ to be true, we must have $c(mn)=c(m)c(n)$ first, but this is the property to be proved, so how to prove the $\Longrightarrow$ part?

Comment: Expand the right-hand side and first equate coefficients of primes, then of prime powers, then of products of prime powers.

Comment: people are affraid of dirichlet series and euler products, probably because they don't know the theorem that as for power series, term to term identification works ! if $\sum a_n n^{-s} = \sum b_n n^{-s}$ (these 2 series converging somewhere), then $a_n = b_n$ for every $n$. it works as for power series :
if $\sum c_n z^{n} = \sum d_n z^{n}$ (these 2 series converging somewhere), then $c_n = d_n$ for every $n$. thus expanding an euler product is not difficult as you can do it term to term (no need to prove the rest tends to 0..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with a Dirichlet sum
$
\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{c(n)}{n^s}
$
and get a product over primes: this is possible if the coefficients $c(n)$ are given by a multiplicative function (then $c(1)=1$), in other words it's an Euler product.
In general you can only say that
$$
\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{c(n)}{n^s} =\prod_p\sum_{j\geq0}\frac{c(p^{js})}{p^{js}}\;.
$$
If the function $c$ is completely multiplicative, you get 
$$
\prod_p\sum_{j\geq0}\frac{c(p^{js})}{p^{js}}=
\prod_p\sum_{j\geq0}\frac{c(p^{s})^j}{p^{js}}=\prod_p\frac1{1-c(p)p^{-s}}\;,
$$
as for the Dirichlet $L$-series, where $c(n)=\chi(n)$ is a Dirichlet character.
In Serre's example, you don't have this expression, so you can deduce that $c$ is only multiplicative but not completely multiplicative. Then you should focus on the expression for a single prime $p$, investigating the powers of such $p$ to prove the relation you want.